# How to fix implicit declaration of function 'yyerror' problem

Tags: yacc, lex

Hi I am making a program that does simple arithmetic operations using Lex and yacc, but I am having a problem with a specific error.

ex1.y

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
int sym[26];
%}

%token INTEGER VARIABLE
%left '+' '-'
%left '*' '/' '%'

%%
program:
    program statement '\n'
    |
    ;

statement:
    expr            {printf("%d\n", $1);}
    | VARIABLE '=' expr {sym[$1] = $3;}
    ;

expr:
    INTEGER
    | VARIABLE      { $$ = sym[$1];}
    | expr '+' expr { $$ = $1 + $3;}
    | expr '-' expr { $$ = $1 - $3;}
    | expr '*' expr     { $$ = $1 * $3;}
    | expr '/' expr { $$ = $1 / $3;}
    | '(' expr ')'      { $$ = $2;}
    ;
%%

main() { return yyparse();}

int yyerror(char *s){
    fprintf(stderr,"%s\n",s);
    return 0;
}
```

ex1.l

```
%{
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "y.tab.h"
%}

%%

    /* variables */
[a-z]  {
        yylval = *yytext -'a';
        return VARIABLE;
    }
    
    /* integers */ 
[0-9]+ {
        yylval = atoi(yytext);
        return INTEGER;
    }

    /* operators */
[-+()=/*\n] { return *yytext;}

    /* skip whitespace */
[ \t]   ;

    /* anything else is an error */
.   yyerror("invalid character");

%%

int yywrap (void){
    return 1;
}
```

when I execute bellow instruction

> $bison –d -y ex1.y

> $lex ex1.l

> $gcc lex.yy.c y.tab.c –o ex1

The following error occurs:

```
ex1.l: In function ‘yylex’:
ex1.l:28:1: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘yyerror’; did you mean ‘perror’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   28 | 
      | ^      
      | perror
y.tab.c: In function ‘yyparse’:
y.tab.c:1227:16: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘yylex’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
 1227 |       yychar = yylex ();
      |                ^~~~~
y.tab.c:1402:7: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘yyerror’; did you mean ‘yyerrok’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
 1402 |       yyerror (YY_("syntax error"));
      |       ^~~~~~~
      |       yyerrok
```

I don't know what is wrong with my code. I would appreciate it if you could tell me how to fix the above error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version of bison you are using requires you to declare prototypes for yylex() and yyerror. These should go right after the `#include <stdio.h>` at the top of the file:

```c
    int yylex(void);
    int yyerror(char* s);
```

I would use `int yyerror(const char* s)` as the prototype for `yyerror`, because it is more accurate, but if you do that you'll have to make the same change in the definition.

You use `yyerror` in your lex file, so you will have to add its declaration in that file as well.

`main()` hasn't been a valid prototype any time this century. Return types are required in function declarations, including `main()`. So I guess you are basing your code on a very old template. There are better starting points in the [examples in the bison manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Examples).
(And don't expect it to be easy to work with parser generators if you have no experience with C.)